# Is this a MySQL bug or is my query wrong?

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I run into some sql weirdness. I had a query that melted the server so, trying to improve it, I made this query:

```
SELECT idEvent, MAX( fechaHora ) , codAgente, evento FROM eventos_centralita GROUP BY codAgente
```

And it *seems* to work for this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eventos_centralita` (
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fechaHora` datetime NOT NULL,
  `codAgente` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evento` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEvent`),
  KEY `codAgente` (`codAgente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=105847 ;
```

I mean, that the hour it's indeed the MAX one for the agent. However, the id of the event and the event itself is wrong...

So, is this a bug or is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing an aggregate function and a "normal" column select. This "feature" only works in MySQL and returns a random id.

Normally you should group by a specific column and the use aggregate functions to select all other columns not in that group. Example:

```
SELECT e1.codAgente, e1.idEvent, e1.fechaHora, e1.evento
FROM eventos_centralita e1
inner join 
(
    select codAgente, MAX(fechaHora) as fechaHora
    from eventos_centralita
    group by codAgente
) e2 
on e1.codAgente = e2.codAgente and e1.fechaHora = e2.fechaHora
```

Comment: ... and the ID is not even random, it's just arbitrary.

Comment: So it is not possible to have MAX and normal fields all together in one query? Would it be necessary to have one `SELECT MAX...` and then one `SELECT items`?

Comment: And how is this supposed to work? I need to get the last event for every agent

Comment: @AntonioLaguna - Do you know how to use the `GROUP BY` clause? We all thought you were talking about MySQL's "feature" where missing `GROUP BY` does not trigger an error.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna: The example above gives you an output. But what exactly do you want to show for each `codAgente`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that to the query, it's on the query as of now. I'll update it

Comment: @juergend I want to show the last event on that table for each agent.

Comment: It throws `FUNCTION e2.min does not exist` and, just curious, why do you use MIN on the id?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna: Sorry, typo. Fixed now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25145/discussion-between-antonio-laguna-and-juergen-d)